# Заполнение товарных позиций в WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Допустим, есть сайт, где 500 товарных позиций. 
Например, [вот такой сайт](http://x-moda.ru/catalog/zhenschinam/zhenskaya_odezhda/futbolki/?yclid=5835684513686007819). 
Понимаю, что магазины лучше делать на OpenCart, но руки до нее пока не дошли. Я могу понять, что там есть главные категории, есть вложенные. Как категории делаются на WP представляю.  Но как происходит заполнение каждой товарной позиции? Я так понимаю, что каждая страница с товаром - это отдельный пост в WordPress. И как набивается информация, например, описание товара, его фотография? Каждый такой пост заполняется в ручную? И так все 500 страниц?! Я думаю, что это не так. В общем, прошу сразу не смеяться,  а хотя бы в общих чертах пояснить, как все это происходит. Можно со ссылкой на туториал, на русском или английском. И еще вопрос. Можно выбрать тему, которую я хочу или сразу лучше выбирать тему с WooCommerce?

Буду очень признательна за совет.

Comment: > Понимаю, что магазины лучше делать на OpenCart

опенкарт - одна из худших систем на свете.

Comment: Спорить не буду, никогда не работала. Мне бы сейчас по WordPress узнать, поскольку буду работать на ней. Мне нужно механизм понять.

Comment: Если точно необходим WP то лучше сразу смотреть в сторону  WooCommerce. 

Все товары обычно заполняются руками либо выгрузкой из какой либо существующей БД.

Comment: Commandante, спасибо за комментарий! Теперь я поняла. Слышала про выгрузку из 1C, но это не мой случай. Придется руками. А что посоветуйте с темой: можно выбрать любую для магазина и встроить плагин или только сразу с встроенным плагином WooCommerce?

Comment: Если Вам нужно массово загрузить много товаров, то для этого есть плагины импорта из csv (эксель), xml и пр.

Comment: Че это опенкарт одна из худших))) В снг она популярней чем вукомерс, конечно в ней есть минусы которые для норм работы надо дорабатывать особенно с сео. В каждой цмс свои плюсы и минусы. Вукомерс это вообще плагин к wp... в котором с url тоже беда.

Answer (score 1):

Вот топ [популярных систем](https://habrahabr.ru/post/296668/) для Интернет-магазинов. WooCommerce и Magento лидируют с большим отрывом, занимая примерно одинаковые доли рынка. OpenCart примерно в 7 раз менее популярен.

Можно делать магазин на WordPress и без WooCommerce, примерно так, как Вы описали. Есть такой плагин российской разработки под названием [wp-shop](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-shop-original/). Но его возможности и близко не сравнимы с WooCommerce, которая также предлагает [очень детальную техническую документацию](https://docs.woocommerce.com/documentation/plugins/woocommerce/woocommerce-codex/), постоянные обновления, массу расширений и дополнительных плагинов под самые разные нужды.

Заполнять созданный на WooCommerce магазин можно как вручную, так и с помощью разнообразных плагинов импорта из xls или иных файлов. Конечно, возможно заполнение и с помощью своего кода. Мне приходилось, например, заносить 14 тысяч товаров в WooCommerce через SOAP - онлайн протокол доступа к базе данных поставщика.

Кстати, еще один миф, связанный с WooCommerce - дескать, система не выдержит большого количества товаров. Ничего подобного. По ощущениям, на упомянутый сайт на данном виртуальном сервере (Digital Ocean, 4ГБ оперативной памяти) можно было и 100 тыс товаров загрузить.

Принцип работы WooCommerce немногим отличается от того, как Вами описано. Товар - это запись специального типа product (в этом отличие от wp-shop, где обычные записи). Дальше - метаданные у каждой записи product и категории, в которые можно объединять продукты.

По поводу темы. Выбирать тему надо только такую, которая явно заявляет поддержку WooCommerce. В противном случае возникнет много мелких проблем в ходе разработки сайта.